# Drush behaves strangely on Windows 10 with Acquia Dev Desktop

Tags: drush, acquia-dev-desktop

After having istalled drush via composer locally I had to make the following changes inside sites\default\settings.php for it to work:

- Create the database connection array

  ```
  $databases['default']['default'] = array (
    'database' => 'Drupal',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '33067',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'prefix' => '',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
  );
  ```
- Add the following line

  ```
  $settings['hash_salt'] = 'CHANGE_THIS';
  ```

After that, Drush works on my 8.6.11 drupal site. However, on Drupal 8.7.1, I get the following exception when running almost all commands.

> In bootstrap.inc line 212:
>
> The configuration directory type 'sync' does not exist

Strangely enough, `drush cr` works fine.

Do I have to create some new directories? May it be connected to the fact that in Drupal 8.7.1 there is no longer a *web* sub-directory in root?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Drupal doesn't create any *web* directory. That is the directory created, for example from [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project). Updating to Drupal 8.7.1 would not remove a *web* directory. Anyway, the error is saying it doesn't find the *sync* directory. Check where that directory is and check where the settings.php file is searching that directory.

Comment: @kiamlaluno How do I check where settings.php is searching for the 'sync' directory?

Comment: Once Drupal is installed, the settings.php file contains a line initializing `$config_directories['sync']`, similar to `$config_directories['sync'] = 'sites/default/files/config_2D33-GIrfpU66Rle01AJsMJiVjrvmDkRuqic0XY_tqnqFFK1qjg9oZ2uv0MnKmgKtJd_IqdoJg/sync';`.  It is usually one of the last lines in the settings.php file.